# django admin fieldsets only show specific choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have fieldsets in admin.py as

fieldsets = ((None, {
    'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'status')
}),)

where `status` is

```
 status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=STATUS, default='good')
```

with choices

```
STATUS = (('good', 'Good'),
          ('bad', 'Bad'),
          ('very_bad', 'Very Bad'),
          ('very_good', 'Very Good'))
```

And I can see in change model admin page `status` with drop down menu with above 4 options.
But is there way to only show 2 options in drop-down menu. e.g. good and bad?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['status'].choices = (('good', 'Good'), ('bad', 'Bad'),)

        return form
```